# Why does the license link take me to Stack Overflow's license page?

Tags: bug, design, stack-exchange, licensing

The license information in the lower right corner of every page  links to https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing instead of to the site's (existing) corresponding page (for example, [on the Cross Validated site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/licensing)) -- is this a mistake in the site customizations, or on purpose?

I originally discovered this on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) and originally asked this [on their meta](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6250/why-does-the-license-link-take-me-to-stack-overflows-license-page) (deleted now; link for users with enough rep) but based on feedback there and elsewhere, and the fact that I see the same symptom e.g. on [Super User](https://superuser.com/), I decided to delete that post and ask here instead for better visibility.

In [a comment there,](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6250/why-does-the-license-link-take-me-to-stack-overflows-license-page#comment21093_6250) Andrew T. notes the same problem with the Privacy Policy and Terms of Service links in the footer, though those are under the "Company" headline and as such might really belong on Stack Overflow (?)

In [another comment there,](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6250/why-does-the-license-link-take-me-to-stack-overflows-license-page#comment21096_6250) Stephan Kolassa points to [Licensing per Site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273091/licensing-per-site) and notes that in the light of that, it might make sense for the license to be stored in one place only (but I'm not particularly convinced; many other help pages are just boilerplate which I imagine will be easy to cross-link between sites server-side where they are identical).

Comment: Seems to be already reported here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372518/169312 ... Should I close this?